# Do namespaces affect the 1 sec per write per entity group?

Tags: namespaces, google-cloud-datastore

I'm achieving strong consistency by making all the entities in my gcloud datastore schema the ancestor of a single root entity. The entities are also being partitioned by a namespace for each user. So the key for each entity looks like

```
[per-user namespace] -> ["RootEntityKind", CONSTANT] -> ["ChildEntityKind", Child_UUID]
```

So for the purposes of the 1 sec / write / entity group limit, if I have N namespaces, does this mean that I have N entity groups or just one?

Comment: This 1s limitation will disappear with the [new Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/upgrade-to-firestore#cloud_firestore_in_datastore_mode). If this is a potential issue in your system, you could think about migrating. Advantages: all Cloud Datastore queries become strongly consistent, transactions are no longer limited to 25 entity groups, and writes to an entity group are no longer limited to 1 per second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Cloud Datastore, root entities in different namespaces are in different entity groups. This means for N namespaces, you'll have N entity groups.

In the new Datastore mode of Cloud Firestore, the [recently announced](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/expanding-the-cloud-firestore-beta-to-more-users) upgrade to Cloud Datastore, there is no longer any entity group based limitations. You also no longer need to use entity groups to achieve strong consistency.